# In R, How do I bucket a list of data according to a column value

Tags: r

I have a large (500K Row) Data frame (named DF) of two columns first being unique identifier (not monotonically increasing), second being size in integer such as:

```
ID,        Size
"K0012234",2335
"K0012345",12
"K0012387",1213
"K0012393",828
"K0012400",123
```

I need to group these items to according to a certain total size sequencially. Although each element in the result set is a single comma delimeted string, it may contain variable number of elements, For example for a given BoxSize=2500, I need to have a list of strings

```
L[0]<-"K0012234,K0012345"
L[1]<-"K0012387,K0012393,K0012400"
```

What is the best way to achive this using R?

If I was coding this in another language I would probably need a function with for loop with an if statement. I am not proficient in doing this in R but algorithm should look something like below (It is meant to give the idea, I know it has some minor errors):

```
boxSize=2500
CurrentTotal=0
box=""
NumberOfRows<-length(DF$ID)
For(int i=0;i<NumberOfRows;i++)
{
   if (CurrentTotal<boxSize)
   {
     box=box+","+DF$ID[i]
     CurrentTotal=CurrentTotal+DF$Size[i]
   }
   else
    {
      L.add(box)
      box=DF$ID
      CurrentTotal=DF$Size[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this we can use the library `MESS` which has the convenient `cumsumbinning` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MESS)

df1 %>% mutate(bins = cumsumbinning(Size, 2500)) %>% 
  group_by(bins) %>% 
  summarize(ID = paste(ID, collapse = ",")) %>%
  select(-bins)


# A tibble: 2 x 1
  ID                        
  <chr>                     
1 K0012234,K0012345         
2 K0012387,K0012393,K0012400
    
Data:

df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("K0012234", "K0012345", 
"K0012387", "K0012393", "K0012400"), class = "factor"), Size = c(2335, 
12, 1213, 828, 123)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

For completeness, if you don't like the package dependency, you could define a function like this to create the bins:

```
cumsum_bins <- function(x, size){
    result <- c()
    bin <- 1
    bucketTotal <- 0
    for (i in seq_along(x)){
        bucketTotal <- bucketTotal + x[i]
        if (bucketTotal >= size){
            bin <- bin + 1
            bucketTotal <- x[i]
            result[i] <- bin
        } else {
            result[i] <- bin
        }
    }
    return(result)
}
```